# error in SQL syntax creating a database table

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

I'm trying to create a table in my database in mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24,

I want a table with two columns:

- one to store text
- one to store long integer to index the text field,

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    tag MEDIUMTEXT,
    index BIGINT(20)
) 
ENGINE MyISAM;
```

But I get the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIGINT(20)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: `index` is a reserved word in MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: I can understand voting to close a question like this (either duplicate or typographical error).  But down voting?  Especially for a new person on the site?  That doesn't seem friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) in MySQL (and any other relational database I can think of). It's used to create, well, [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html).

In MySQL you can escape object names by enclosing them with ` characters:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    tag MEDIUMTEXT, 
    `index` BIGINT(20) 
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

But it's generally considered a better practice to avoid such cases completely. For example, you could call the numeric column `tag_index`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    tag MEDIUMTEXT, 
    tag_index BIGINT(20) 
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```